# Git conflict in two branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have Two branch , Master and Staging. right now those two have same code version. any how I did some changes to Staging and try to merge that to master I am getting Conflict file message. I am using bitbucket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use Github for ease
remove conflict with symbols first
======== or <<<<<<<<<
then open git shell
using command you can solve conflict coming during merge
cmd is
1  git status
2 git add then press tab button or type path of conflict file
3 again check git status
4 now color of file change from red to green
5 type cmd , git commit
6 then git push
now all set check using cmd git status
```

Comment: Thanks sunil for you answere. that not what i expect. when change Staging branch and try to merge that Master branch then get conflict in master branch. thing is I am not change any thing in master branch.

Comment: using cmd check what is git status of branch

Answer (score 0):

Use `compareit` tool that helps you to compare files and show changes.

look at here http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm

Answer (score 0):

I cloud find the solution my self. what happened, I replace Staging Branch with master so when files changed in Staging branch even no changes in Master branch git gives every time  "File has modified in both side". because two branch point to same header. to resolved this issue we need rebase each branch agian. command is git --rebase "origine/master" --force /git --rebase "origine/Staging" --force
after that each branch's header point from each other.